# Compare large files

Tags: delphi, compare

I have some files (3-5) that i need to compare:
File 1.txt have 1 million strings.
File 2.txt have 10 million strings.
File 3.txt have 5 million strings.
All these files are compared with file keys.txt (10 thousand strings). If line from currently opened file is the same as one of lines from keys.txt, write this line into output.txt (I hope you understand what i mean).

Now i have:

```
function Thread.checkKeys(sLine: string): boolean;
var
  SR: TStreamReader;
  line: string;
begin
  Result := false;
  SR := TStreamReader.Create(sKeyFile); // sKeyFile - Path to file keys.txt
  try
    while (not(SR.EndOfStream)) and (not(Result))do
      begin
        line := SR.ReadLine;
        if LowerCase(line) = LowerCase(sLine) then
          begin
            saveStr(sLine);
            inc(iMatch);
            Result := true;
          end;
      end;
  finally
    SR.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Thread.saveStr(sToSave: string);
var
  fOut: TStreamWriter;
begin
  fOut := TStreamWriter.Create('output.txt', true, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    fOut.WriteLine(sToSave);
  finally
    fOut.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Thread.updateFiles;
begin
  fmMain.flDone.Caption := IntToStr(iFile);
  fmMain.flMatch.Caption := IntToStr(iMatch);
end;
```

And loop with

```
    fInput := TStreamReader.Create(tsFiles[iCurFile]);
    while not(fInput.EndOfStream) do
      begin
        sInput := fInput.ReadLine;
        checkKeys(sInput);
      end;
    fInput.Free;
    iFile := iCurFile + 1;
    Synchronize(updateFiles);
```

So, if i compare these 3 files with file key.txt it takes about 4 hours. How to decrease compare time?

Comment: My Delphi is rusty, but 10k strings isn't all that much. Just read them into a hashtable or similar in Delphi to do a quick comparison in a loop while you process the other files.

Comment: Cache the output of `saveStr` to a stringlist, and when the search is done, write all at once to the output file.

Comment: @LURD If all 10 millions strings match, you've just run out of memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, flush if size bigger than x.

Comment: @LURD I'd just write to a buffered file stream. In fact, isn't `TStreamWriter` buffered? In which case the code already does what you suggest.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that is ok, if it just wasn't created for every write sequence.

Comment: Ok, tried to load keys once at start into `TArray<string>` and edit function `checkKeys`. Time for 220 millions decreased to 50sec. Is it possible to decrease it more?

Comment: As @LasseV.Karlsen suggested, try using a `THashedStringList` to check against rather than `TArray<string>` (though I've not used a generics-era Delphi, so not sure if there's any other hash implementation in later versions)

Comment: @MattAllwood Thank you, memory drain much less. But speed still 50-55 sec for 1 file (1 million strigns) and keys (200 strings).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, i have 11 thousand uniqe strings.

Comment: You wouldn't use `THashedStringList` these days. See my answer for an example using `TDictionary<TKey,TValue>`. You'll need there to be a lot of keys before you see large benefits of hashed lookup over linear/binary search lookup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy solution is to use an associative container to store your keys. This can provide efficient lookup.

In Delphi you can use `TDictionary<TKey,TValue>` from `Generics.Collections`. The implementation of this container hashes the keys and provides O(1) lookup.

Declare the container like this:

```
Keys: TDictionary<string, Boolean>; 
// doesn't matter what type you use for the value, we pick Boolean since we
// have to pick something
```

Create and populate it like this:

```
Keys := TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create;
SR := TStreamReader.Create(sKeyFile);
try
  while not SR.EndOfStream do
    Keys.Add(LowerCase(SR.ReadLine), True); 
    // exception raised if duplicate key found
finally
  SR.Free;
end;
```

Then your checking function becomes:

```
function Thread.checkKeys(const sLine: string): boolean;
begin
  Result := Keys.ContainsKey(LowerCase(sLine));
  if Result then 
  begin
    saveStr(sLine);
    inc(iMatch);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What if my key is `123` and string is `1234` it will return true or false?

Comment: This code does exactly the same as the code in the question. `ContainsKey` checks whether the **container** contains a specific key. It does not check whether any key in the container contains a fragment!

Comment: Thank you! Now it takes 20sec.

Comment: So, here is code: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VAarDrLr) if you can help me to improve it somehow, it will be great. I want to increase speed a little bit more, is it possible?

Comment: My comments: 1. You are mixing GUI code with processing code. I would not do that. 2. The try/finally in `checkKeys` is pointless and should be removed. 3. The call to `inherited` in `Execute` is pointless and should be removed. 4. `TThread` already has a termination mechanism. Check the `Terminated` property, and terminate by calling `Terminate` on the thread. Remove `bEnabled`. 5. At the end of `Execute` you access VCL objects outside the main thread. Don't do that. 6. If you want the code to run faster, you'll need to work out where the bottle neck is now.

Comment: I fixed #2 and #3. But i have problem. Check pastebin again, i added Button's OnClick code and i dont know how to check if thread is already running or not except with `bEnabled`.

Comment: Remove `bEnabled`. When the user cancels, call `Terminate` on the thread. Inside the thread execute, check the value of the `Terminated` property.

Comment: Ok, updated. But still something slow. Maybe improve method of loading large files? I use `TStreamReader`, is it fastest or dont?

Comment: I don't think `TStreamReader` is necessarily that fast. You could try increasing the buffer size when you create both `TStreamReader` and `TStreamWriter` instances. You should try to find your bottleneck.

Comment: Realistically, what's the best performance that you can hope for? How long does it take just to read the 20 million line text file? You'll never be able to do it faster than that.

Comment: I have application that check 3 files (4,6,2 million lines) and 1 key.txt (11000 lines) for 3 hours.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no idea what that means. If you want to improve performance, you need to identify a bottleneck. And you need to have a realistic expectation of what can be achieved. Where's the bottleneck now, and what's the best runtime you could expect?

Comment: Now all right. Thank you very much for your help. Programm pass these 3 huge files and key.txt for 30 sec. Thats much faster, than i expect. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should load Keys.txt into for example TStringList. Don't read keys each time from file. The second in such high count loop you shouldn't use procedure/functions calls you should do all checks inline.

Something like this:

```
   Keys:=TStringList.Create;
   Keys.LoadFromFile('keys.txt');

   fInput := TStreamReader.Create(tsFiles[iCurFile]);
   fOut := TStreamWriter.Create('output.txt', true, TEncoding.UTF8);
    while not(fInput.EndOfStream) do
      begin
        sInput := fInput.ReadLine;
        if Keys.IndexOf(sInput)>=0 then
        begin
         fOut.WriteLine(sInput);     
         inc(iMatch);
        end; 

      end;
    fInput.Free;
    fOut.Free;
    iFile := iCurFile + 1;
    Synchronize(updateFiles);

    Keys.Free;
```

Comment: This will help for sure. But `IndexOf` is not the most efficient.

Comment: I agree - the next improvement is to use SORTED array of keys HASH values and search HASH of the input strings in this array.

Comment: Well, sorted or hashed, which is it to be?

Comment: Several threads **should not** write to output.txt. Period. Ultra-period. DON'T DO IT! RUN FOREST, RUN!

Comment: @LURD Only one thread is writing. All this work happens in a single background worker thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, maybe so but not clear from the question. And one aspect to decrease compare time is to run many comparing threads at the same time. Hence my comment to reflect on that part.

Comment: @LURD Threading unlikely to help here. This looks like a disk bound activity to me.